# Angular input is not passing boolean value as it is always true

Tags: angular

Angular input is not passing the boolean value as it is always true

```
<button (click)="isAdded=true">add me</button> //  isAdded is always true and CD doesnt work

<hello [isAdded]=isAdded [myArray]="myArray"></hello>
```

isAdded is always true and CD doesn't work. One way to fix this is to create an object and clone it. Is there any other proper way?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example-1va1m8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: What's `CD`? ChangeDetection? If an input doesn't change you won't be able to catch anything. If you need to check something whenever the button is pressed, despite what's changing, you could implement a method in `HelloComponent` and call it on `(click)` of the button.

Comment: Change detection. need to call a method in hello component whenever the button is clicked. Why have you downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Change Detection kicks in when the input changes, If you pass in `true` then change `true` to `true`, the input has not changed hence no change detection. Angular is just working as expected

As you have stated

> One way to fix this is to create an object and clone it

Another option is to pass in an `Observable<boolean>`. If we trigger the `next()` function with the same input, then change detection will kick in as this is a new stream of value

**child.ts**

```typescript
  isAdded: Observable<boolean>;
  @Input()
  set myArray(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.array = value;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAdded.subscribe({
      next: isAdded => console.log(isAdded)
    });
    console.log("array is", this.array);
  }
```

**parent.html**

```html
<button (click)="isAddedSubject$.next(true)">add me</button>
<hello [isAdded]='isAdded$' [myArray]="myArray"></hello>
```

**parent.ts**

```typescript
  isAddedSubject$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  isAdded$ = this.isAddedSubject$.asObservable()
```

[See this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example-njhdkk?)